# tokio io copy bidirectional on rust, receiver not receiving the data

Tags: rust, proxy, rust-tokio

I want to make a simple proxy, so I wanted to use `tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(stream1, stream2)` provided in tokio Rust's library. I've a problem, the `client1` establishes a connection to `server1` (proxy) and later `server1` establishes a connection to `server2`. The issue is that `server2` never recieve the message from client.

Antoher question: If I want the proxy to read the message from the streams what should I do?

This is the code:

```rust
use std::net::{SocketAddr, ToSocketAddrs};
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
//Import duration

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Initialize the server address
    let server1_addr = "127.0.0.1:8000".to_socket_addrs().unwrap().next().unwrap();

    let server2_addr = "127.0.0.1:9000".to_socket_addrs().unwrap().next().unwrap();

    //Init the server and client
    let server1_handle = tokio::spawn(server1(server1_addr, server2_addr));

    let server2_handle = tokio::spawn(server2(server2_addr));

    let client_handle = tokio::spawn(client(server1_addr));

    // Wait for the server to complete its work
    server1_handle.await.unwrap();
    server2_handle.await.unwrap();
    client_handle.await.unwrap();
}

async fn server1(server1_addr: SocketAddr, server2_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&server1_addr).await.unwrap();
    while let Ok((mut stream1, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        let mut stream2 = TcpStream::connect(&server2_addr).await.unwrap();
        stream2.write_all(b"hello\n").await.unwrap();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(&mut stream1, &mut stream2).await {
                Ok((n1, n2)) => {
                    println!("Server sent {} bytes and received {} bytes", n1, n2);
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Server error: {}", e);
                }
            }
            
        });
        
       
    }
    
}

async fn server2(server2_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&server2_addr).await.unwrap();
    while let Ok((mut socket, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("Server 2 accepted connection");
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let n = socket.read_to_end(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
        println!("Server 2 received {} bytes", n);
        let message = "world\n";
        socket.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        println!(" Server 2 sent message: {:?}", message);
    }
}

async fn client(server1_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let mut socket = TcpStream::connect(&server1_addr).await.unwrap();
    let message = "hello\n";
    socket.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    println!("Client sent message: {:?}", message);
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    socket.read_to_end(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
    println!("Client received message: {:?}", buf);
}
```

Terminal output:

```bash
Client sent message: "hello\n"
Server 2 accepted connection
```

I want to know why I'm having that problem, if I made an incorrect implementation or if there is an error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after `client` sent it's data it does not drop `socket` or at least the writing half of it so you never signal that you're done writing, and in turn `read_to_end` does never finish, since it doesn't know it's at the end yet.
Similarly `server2` doesn't drop the writing part of `socket` either so `client` is stuck waiting for the end in `read_to_end` as well. You can simply `into_split` the `socket` and drop the parts you no longer need to proceed:

```rust
async fn server1(server1_addr: SocketAddr, server2_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&server1_addr).await.unwrap();
    if let Ok((mut stream1, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("server1: accepted connection");
        let mut stream2 = TcpStream::connect(&server2_addr).await.unwrap();
        stream2.write_all(b"hello\n").await.unwrap();
        println!("server1: wrote \"hello\" to server2");
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match tokio::io::copy_bidirectional(&mut stream1, &mut stream2).await {
                Ok((n1, n2)) => {
                    println!("Server sent {} bytes and received {} bytes", n1, n2);
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Server error: {}", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

async fn server2(server2_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&server2_addr).await.unwrap();
    if let Ok((mut socket, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("Server 2 accepted connection");
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let (mut read, mut write) = socket.into_split();
        let n = read.read_to_end(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
        drop(read);
        println!("Server 2 received {} bytes", n);
        let message = "world\n";
        write.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        drop(write);
        println!(" Server 2 sent message: {:?}", message);
    }
}

async fn client(server1_addr: SocketAddr) {
    let (mut read, mut write) = TcpStream::connect(&server1_addr).await.unwrap().into_split();
    let message = "hello\n";
    write.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    drop(write);
    println!("Client sent message: {:?}", message);
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    read.read_to_end(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
    drop(read);
    println!("Client received message: {:?}", buf);
}
```

I've also swapped out `while let` for `if let` because that means the servers also terminate after 1 iteration, that way the program finishes on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6bf377fcd06cdb7e1cb6aef295efd071)